# how to programmatically take a screenshot in react-native

Tags: react-native, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot in ReactNative. I need a screenshot and put it in `Image` component. How could I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a library to do just that: [React Native View Shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)

```js
import RNViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";

RNViewShot.takeSnapshot(viewRef, {
  format: "jpeg",
  quality: 0.8
})
.then(
  uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
  error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to take a screenshot of the whole screen?

Comment: does this library depend on Native Modules

Comment: can we use this for android versions higher than 9?

Comment: @BelginAndroid, yes, the library uses native modules

Answer (score 12):

For a capture of the **currently displayed screen** use `captureScreen()`:

```
import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";

captureScreen({
  format: "jpg",
  quality: 0.8
})
.then(
  uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
  error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
);
```

> This method will capture the contents of the currently displayed
>   screen as a native hardware screenshot. It does not require a ref
>   input, as it does not work at the view level. This means that
>   ScrollViews will not be captured in their entirety - only the portions
>   currently visible to the user.

You can find **more** about the `react-native-view-shot` library [here](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)